# How to clone local svn repository to local git repository?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn, svn2git

Recently I am working on migrating one of my `SVN` repository to Git. I am able to do so if I use my svn repository on internet. But the repository is too big (It has over *60000 commits*) so it is taking a very long time to do so. The internet gets disconnected in between then I have to start over. So, I thought to clone the svn repo onto my local and then clone the local svn repo to local git repo.
BUT I am only able to clone SVN repo to my local and unable to clone it to local git repo. I am using git-svn to do so. I am getting the following error.

> *“Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///c:/gitMigr/repo-svn': Unable to open repository 'file:///c:/gitMigr/repo-svn' at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 310.”*

I already have the `authors.txt` file in my directory. I am using the following command:

```
git svn clone file:///c:/gitMigr/repo-svn --no-metadata -A authors.txt --stdlayout temp
```

Note: **"temp"** is my local git repo name in which I want to clone the svn repo.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -3):

install subversion locally in order to import your dump, then with git-svn package.

You can use `git svn clone file:///path/to/svn/repo /path/to/empty/dir`

Comment: I have git-svn installed. I am able to clone the svn repo to my local machine. But I am not able to clone it to my local git repo.